# How can i use Plotly express to make a 1D histogram without making new x values for each row of the same value?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, plotly-express

This is how my plot actually is: [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWVGZ.png)

This is the Data Frame: [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GANHH.png)

This is my current code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)

df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')

fig= px.bar(df, x='number', y='number', color='profit')
fig.show()
```

As you can see, the sales numbers are many times the same, so i want to plot a histogram being each x value the total profit of all sales with the same key number, so i can compare the profit of each sales key number.

How can i do that using Pandas and plotly express?

ps: I'm a real noobie with all this

Answer (score 0):

- there is something up with your data frame.  Have simulated it and used your code to generate figure.  It generates a very different figure (see first image below)

  - I suspect there is something up with your dataframe,  number columns are not numbers but strings.  check `df.dtypes`
  - this is implied by xaxis being unordered and the fact **color** does not generate a color bar, but uses sequential colors
- have demonstrated approach to getting total profit by sales number.  Aggregate first with **pandas** then plot *number* as xaxis and *profit* as yaxis

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# simulate data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({"number": np.repeat(np.arange(3334, 3389), 6)}).pipe(
    lambda d: d.assign(profit=np.random.uniform(-10, 200, len(d)))
)

# question approach
fig = px.bar(df, x="number", y="number", color="profit")
fig.show()

# requested approach
fig = px.bar(
    df.groupby("number", as_index=False).agg({"profit": "sum"}), x="number", y="profit"
).update_layout(xaxis={"type": "category"})

fig.show()
```

[image]